# does this still cause memory leak in ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

This is the scenario: 
suppose we have a MyObject class, and we declare a property by `@property (strong) NSObject *aObj` in "MyObject.h"; then we use this property in "MyObject.m".

```
A. self.aObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];

B. aObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

I wonder whether there are memory leaks with A. it seems in MRC if the strong is retain, A will case memory leaks. if in ARC, this still cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, under ARC, neither causes a memory leak. ARC is smart enough to handle these cases.

Comment: Because ARC will add an autorelease call to the object you are allocating. ARC know when to call retain, release, and autorelease. It does it better than us silly humans ever could. If, under MRC, you knew to add a call to autorelease, then ARC knows it should too.

Comment: @rmaddy - ARC can actually do better (which doesn't mean it always will) and it may release where under MRC you would have autoreleased. For case (A) ARC can release immediately after the assignment, equivalent to the MRC code `NSObject *tmp = [[NSObject alloc] init]; self.aObj = tmp; [tmp release];`

Comment: @CRD True. But the great thing about ARC is I don't have to care. :)

Answer (score 0):

(A) will leak in MRC, the RHS returns an owned object and the property setter retains this as second time. It will not leak in ARC.

(B) may leak in MRC, the variable `aObj` may contain an owned reference which will not be released. It will not leak in ARC.

Comment: can you explain why (A) wont leak in ARC?

Comment: @chancy - ARC knows you own the RHS and therefore that it needs to be released after the current expression as it can be no longer accessed (i.e. it wasn't stored into a local variable).